# Keep Amazon Linux Workspace alive when client has no connection to it

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I have an Amazon Linux workspace which I'm running a python job on. The job requires a GUI to complete successfully (XVFB wasn't suitable for this).

I'd like to keep the code running even if my client doesn't have a connection to the workspace.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.